How to use Mathematica to obtain the Green function for the third boundary value problem of the parabolic equation?
I see that in the official documentation, there are only instructions for the first or second boundary value problems.

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=a \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}+\Phi(x, t)$
with Domain: $0 \leq x<\infty$. Third boundary value problem. The following conditions are prescribed: $$ \begin{array}{rlll} &w=f(x)  &\text { at }  t=0  \text { (initial condition), } \\ &\partial_x w-k w  =g(t) \quad &\text { at }  x=0  \text { (boundary condition). } \end{array} $$

Although the textbook provides the Green Function for this problem, I still want to know if Mathematica can solve this problem on its own?
For information on this issue in the textbook, please refer to the link: https://ibb.co/HV2JnS2


Could you please provide the exact equation you are trying to solve with these boundary conditions please?

@chris I have already made the modification, please refer to it. The main complexity lies in $\Phi(x,t)$. However, my current issue is whether Mathematica can automatically provide the Green function for the third type of boundary?

@user21 would probably know the answer to this generic question?

Not an answer but a comment.
One can use mathematica to check that the solution provided from the PDF works.
Let us define
G[x_, \[Xi]_, t_] = 
 1/2/Sqrt[Pi  a  t] (Exp[-(x - \[Xi])^2/4/a/t] + 
    Exp[-(x + \[Xi])^2/4/a/t] - 
    2  k  Integrate[
      Exp[-(x + \[Xi] + \[Eta])^2/4/a/t - k  \[Eta] ], {\[Eta], 0, 
       Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False])


We check that it satisfies the boundary conditions.
D[G[x, \[Xi], t], t] - a  D[G[x, \[Xi], t], x, x] // FullSimplify

(* 0 *)

D[G[x, \[Xi], t], x] - k  G[x, \[Xi], t] /. x -> 0 // FullSimplify

(*  0  *)

Now the full solution with a left hand side should be
ws[x_, t_] = 
 Integrate[f[\[Xi]] G[x, \[Xi], t], {\[Xi], 0, Infinity}] - 
  a  Integrate[g[\[Tau]] G[x, 0, t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t}] + 
  Inactive@
   Integrate[\[CapitalPhi][x, \[Tau]] G[x, \[Xi], 
      t - \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 0, t},
    {\[Xi], 0, Infinity}]


Let us define the PDE it is supposed to satisfy
eqn = D[G[x, \[Xi], t], t] - 
   a  D[G[x, \[Xi], t], x, x] - \[CapitalPhi][x, t];

Indeed
eqn /. w -> Function[{x, t}, ws[x, t] // Rest // Evaluate] // Simplify

(*   -[CapitalPhi](x,t) *)
Which may look incorrect at first but just reflects that the first term, if active, would actually return \[CapitalPhi](x,t) so that it cancels out to zero.
As a complement you might want to look at this answer

Thank you very much for your response. I have a fundamental question. Please see my revised question: I want to reproduce a semi-analytical form from an article. Can Mathematica solve the recursive integral form of the PDE $U_0$ for the standard B-S lookback option?(I found it almost impossible to solve the integral directly using Mathematica.)

@YilinCheng The problem in the update is rather different from the original, please avoid asking distinctly different questions in one post, consider asking a new question.

@xzczd Thanks, I will add a new question.

@chris Thanks,  If you have any ideas for a follow-up question, I would greatly appreciate it.   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/301776/94893
