How to solve the following complex integral?
I am currently trying to reproduce a semi-analytical solution, where $U_0$ satisfies the PDE under the Black-Scholes model, $\mathcal{M}$ represents some differential operators, such as derivatives with respect to time $t$. Given such a complex recursive form involving the integrals of $U_n$, can Mathematica handle it? I found myself quite foolish as I directly used Integrate and failed to obtain a solution.



My code  is:
T = 1;
r = 0.04;
kappa = 1;
theta = 0.25;
sigma = 0.1;

eta[\[Tau]_, x_, v_] := 
 Exp[-1/8 v (2 r/v + 1)^2 \[Tau] + 1/2 (2 r/v + 1) x]
dmPlus[t_, x_, v_] := (-x + (r + v/2) (T - t))/Sqrt[v (T - t)]
dmMinus[t_, x_, v_] := (-x + (r - v/2) (T - t))/Sqrt[v (T - t)]
dmR[t_, x_, v_] := dmPlus[t, x, v] - 2 r/Sqrt[v] Sqrt[T - t]
G[t_, x_, \[Xi]_, v_] := 
 1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi] v t])*(Exp[-(x - \[Xi])^2/(2 v t)] + 
    Exp[-(x + \[Xi])^2/(2 v t)] + (2 r/v + 1) Integrate[
      Exp[-(x + \[Xi] + \[Eta])^2/(2 v t) + 
        0.5 (2 r/v + 1) \[Eta]], {\[Eta], 0, \[Infinity]}, 
      Assumptions -> 
       1/(t v) > 0 && (0.04` t - 1.` x - 1.` \[Xi])/(t v) < -0.5])
normal[z_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], z]

U0[t_, x_, v_] := 
 Exp[x] Exp[-r (T - t)] normal[-dmMinus[t, x, v]] - 
  normal[-dmPlus[t, x, v]] + 
  v/(2 r) (Exp[-r (T - t)] normal[dmPlus[t, x, v]] - 
     Exp[x + 2 x r/v] normal[dmR[t, x, v]])
MU0[t_, x_, v_] := 
 kappa (theta - v) D[U0[t, x, v], v] + 
  0.5 sigma^2 v D[D[U0[t, x, v], v], v]
Uhat[\[Tau]_, x_, v_] := 
 Integrate[
  Integrate[
   eta[s, \[Xi], v] *MU0[T - s, \[Xi], v] *
    G[\[Tau] - s, x, \[Xi], v], {\[Xi], 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Assumptions -> \[Tau] > s > 0 && x > 0 && v > 0], {s, 0, \[Tau]}]


"I directly used Integrate and failed to obtain a solution." This sounds strange, coding such recursive formula in Mathematica should be straightforward. How do you try using Integrate? Please show us the code. (Notice you may need Inactive to avoid unnecessary integration. )

Another thing that's worth mentioning is, you cannot directly differentiate the integral using D, see the following 2 posts for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223456/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223880/1871

@xzczd I posted my code, but found that Uhat cannot be solved. How can I solve this issue? Thanks

I don't understand your code: it does not seem to code the recursion.  You should have something like U[n_,..]:= U[n, ... ] = function of (U[n-1,...])

@chris Yes, you are right. The Uhat  I am solving for now corresponds to $n=1$, but I am stuck at the step from $n=0$ to $n=1$.

You might need something like this: ClearAll[U];
U[1][x] = x;
U[n_][x_] :=
U[n][x] =
Integrate[U[n - 1][x]  Exp[-(x - y)^2] // Evaluate, {x, 0, y}] /.
y -> x`

@chris Thank you, this is a very good approach for me, your advice is very helpful. If you are interested, you can take a look at why the Uhat in the code cannot be solved. Is there an issue with my code (I am currently not very skilled in using Mathematica)?

Are you expecting something free of Integrate? If so, are you sure it always exists? Also, you should not abuse :=. (Since you can read Chinese, check this: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare/index.html?id=509049223cd2f6b2519cfef71d4b900b&type=note&_time=1712904393435 )

@xzczd Thank you, I will go read the documentation at Youdao.

Notice that even Integrate[eta[s, ξ, v] MU0[T - s, ξ, v] G[τ - s, x, ξ, v] /. {s -> 1, v -> 2, x -> 3, τ -> 4}, {ξ, 0, ∞}] returns unevaluated. I don't think a closed form integral exists for your problem.

@xzczd I obtained a numerical result using NIntegrate, does this imply that the integrand function is too complicated?Thanks.

As mentioned in my last comment, the closed form result may simply doesn't exist. (Not surprising, the integrand involves Erfc. ) If analytic result isn't necessary, it's time to switch to numeric integral. If it's necessary, then, as asked above, are you sure such a result exists?

@xzczd  thank you very much. I will rethink my question.

@xzczd Thanks, and  I have a question about zooming in on images. If you are interested: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/301778/94893
