Local zoomed-in image?
I want to use a local zoomed-in image. The code is as follows. As you can see, in the zoomed-in image, the 'PlotLabels' such as "Min" and "RF" are not displayed completely. However, there is a noticeable blank space where 'PlotLabels' can be inserted. How can this issue be resolved?

ttt = Table[{5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 
   50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000}]
ttttt = {0.5411080105624226`, 0.4746114896441091`, 
  0.45560476211921547`, 0.3920375515864554`, 0.3688071154680211`, 
  0.37303695707239365`, 0.35986703180178964`, 0.3454025968800972`, 
  0.33737968696907666`, 0.332893155320118`, 0.330917731450119`, 
  0.328349013701957`, 0.3275433810401204`, 0.32654069972569133`, 
  0.32644824704879566`, 0.17576476308174965`, 0.14935405824951864`, 
  0.20544610516687922`, 0.23442829580276892`, 0.2794037021607155`, 
  0.28917713986193516`, 0.30219001700545106`, 0.3100617228918656`, 
  0.31501426509592156`, 0.3178735474098285`, 0.32019011261868147`, 
  0.32284032044479144`, 0.32405254386607507`, 0.32405254386607507`, 
  0.32405254386607507`}
ans1 = ListPlot[Table[{ttt[[i]], ttttt[[i]]}, {i, 15}], 
   Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabels -> Callout["Max", {Scaled[0], Above}], PlotStyle -> Red];
ans2 = ListPlot[Table[{ttt[[i]], ttttt[[i + 15]]}, {i, 15}], 
   Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabels -> Callout["Min", {Scaled[0], Above}], 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
ans3 = ListPlot[Table[{ttt[[i]], 0.32488628166902345`}, {i, 15}], 
   Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabels -> Callout["RF", {Scaled[0], Above}]];
Show[ans1, ans2, ans3, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Path number", MaTeX[Q]}]
ans4 = ListPlot[Table[{ttt[[i]], ttttt[[i]]}, {i, 13, 15}], 
   Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabels -> Callout["Max", {Scaled[0], Above}], PlotStyle -> Red];
ans5 = ListPlot[Table[{ttt[[i]], ttttt[[i + 15]]}, {i, 13, 15}], 
   Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabels -> Callout["Min", {Scaled[0], Above}], 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
ans6 = ListPlot[Table[{ttt[[i]], 0.32488628166902345`}, {i, 13, 15}], 
   Joined -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabels -> Callout["RF", {Scaled[1], Above}]];
Show[ans4, ans5, ans6, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {Log[10^5], 0.32}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Path number", MaTeX[Q]}, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
xyMinMax = {{Log[10^5], Log[10^6]}, {0.31, 0.34}};
Show[{ans1, ans2, ans3}, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Path number", MaTeX[Q]}, 
 Epilog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[Thick], 
   Rectangle[Sequence @@ Transpose[xyMinMax]], 
   Inset[Show[ans4, ans5, ans6, 
     PlotRange -> {{Log[10^5], Log[10^6]}, {0.32, 0.33}}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {Log[10^5], 0.3}, 
     AxesLabel -> {"Path number", MaTeX[Q]}, Frame -> True, 
     ImageSize -> 200], {10., 0.5}]}, ImageSize -> 600]

My specific issue is, you can see on the main picture there are three labels: "Min," "Max," and "RF." But in the zoomed-in part of the image, strangely, "Min" and "RF" are both moved out of the image area, causing them not to be fully displayed. I hope they can be displayed properly in the image. (I need the "RF" and "Min" labels in the zoomed-in image to be positioned close to "Max." Of course, I can make the zoomed-in image very large to properly display these two labels, but that is not what I want.)
Here is a solution
ClearAll["Global`*"]

df = {5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 
   100000, 500000, 1000000};
df2 = {0.5411080105624226`, 0.4746114896441091`, 0.45560476211921547`,
    0.3920375515864554`, 0.3688071154680211`, 0.37303695707239365`, 
   0.35986703180178964`, 0.3454025968800972`, 0.33737968696907666`, 
   0.332893155320118`, 0.330917731450119`, 0.328349013701957`, 
   0.3275433810401204`, 0.32654069972569133`, 0.32644824704879566`, 
   0.17576476308174965`, 0.14935405824951864`, 0.20544610516687922`, 
   0.23442829580276892`, 0.2794037021607155`, 0.28917713986193516`, 
   0.30219001700545106`, 0.3100617228918656`, 0.31501426509592156`, 
   0.3178735474098285`, 0.32019011261868147`, 0.32284032044479144`, 
   0.32405254386607507`, 0.32405254386607507`, 0.32405254386607507`};

refLine = {{5, 0.324}, {10^6, 0.324}};
refLine2 = {{10^5, 0.324}, {10^6, 0.324}};
xyMinMax = {{Log[10^5], Log[10^6]}, {0.31, 0.34}};

insetPlot = 
  ListLinePlot[{refLine2, Transpose@{df[[13 ;; 15]], df2[[13 ;; 15]]},
     Transpose@{df[[13 ;; 15]], df2[[28 ;; 30]]}}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red, Cyan}, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 230, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, All}}];

ListLinePlot[{refLine, Transpose@{df, df2[[;; 15]]}, 
  Transpose@{df, df2[[16 ;;]]}}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log"}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.1, 0.7}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"RF", "Max", "Min"}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &)], {Left, 
    Top}], PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red, Cyan}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Path number", "MaTeX(Q)"}, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 Epilog -> {{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Thick], 
    Rectangle[Sequence @@ Transpose[xyMinMax]], Dashed, 
    Line[{{Log[10^5], 0.34}, {Log[10^4], 0.405}}], 
    Line[{{Log[10^6], 0.34}, {Log[10^6] - 0.2, 0.405}}]}, 
   Inset[insetPlot, Scaled[{0.78, 0.7}]]}]



@user64494 No, I may not have explained it clearly. My specific issue is, you can see on the main picture there are three labels: "Min," "Max," and "RF." But in the zoomed-in part of the image, strangely, "Min" and "RF" are both moved out of the image area, causing them not to be fully displayed. I hope they can be displayed properly in the image.

@user64494 I tried changing the numbers for theScaled , but none of them had a very good effect. I need the "RF" and "Min" labels in the zoomed-in image to be positioned close to "Max." Of course, I can make the zoomed-in image very large to properly display these two labels, but that is not what I want.

For things like this, I export both of the plots—without labels—as .svg and then edit something like Inkscape.

@CraigCarter Thanks, your suggestion is very good. If there are no other methods, I will adjust it manually.

You should have added the further explanation to the body of question. Also, once again, please put a bit more effort in providing a minimal working example: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871

@OkkesDulgerci Thank your solution  very much.
